# createPlatformApplication throwing Server error 500 with sample code AWS SNS PUSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to follow steps mentioned at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html site to develop a sample push service for aws sns. I keep getting the below mentioned error

===========================================

## Getting Started with Amazon SNS

Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon SNS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
Error Message:    Request could not be completed (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 500; Error Code: InternalError; Request ID: a630491b-19c2-58cf-8081-05477accfdda)
HTTP Status Code: 500
AWS Error Code:   InternalError
Error Type:       Service
Request ID:       a630491b-19c2-58cf-8081-05477accfdda

Can someone please help me with this? I know all the credentials are correct because when I try to use a name of my existing application, it tells me that an app with the same name already exists.

Comment: Having the same problem—did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Having the same problem. I even posted it but no reply has anyone solved it?.

Comment: The answer below by Vincent Cavell works! (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37134886/1433774)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it. I realised that the .pem file provided by Apple contained multiple certificates, so I extracted the correct certificate and everything is working great now.

Instead of obtaining the App Private Key like that:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myapnsappprivatekey.p12 -out myapnsappprivatekey.pem -nodes -clcerts
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-push-apns.html#private-key-apns

Use:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in myapnsappprivatekey.p12 -out myapnsappprivatekey.pem -nodes -nocerts
```